# How do I send and receive broadcast messages using QT 4.5 and Linux?

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm new to QT programming. Could anyone explain how I can send broadcast messages given a network adapter and its IP address? I also don't know how to receive datagrams using QT. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

You could conceivably take a look at the very simple BroadcastSender and BroadcastReceiver examples that come bundled with QT. You will find them in the `examples/network` directory of your QT source tree, more specifically in `examples/network/broadcastreceiver` and `examples/network/broadcastsender` or directly online at this URL: [examples/network](http://labs.trolltech.com/gitweb?p=qt/snapshot/4.5;a=tree;f=examples/network;h=585775d6860bfeca55ef428bc029001771926882;hb=HEAD)